# Unable to copy list to set. 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, set

```
lst,score_set,final_lst = [],[],[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        score_set.append(score)
        lst.append(([name,score]))

    new_set = set()
    for i in range(0,len(score_set)):
        item = score_set[i]
        print (item)
        new_set.update(item)
```

I am trying to copy a list into a set to remove duplicates. In my code, if I remove the last line, the code runs fine. Could you guys please help ?

Comment: `li = [1,2,3,2,3,2,3,4]` -> `s = set(li)` - done ?

Comment: Why do you even build a list? Just use a set in the first place.

Comment: As for the error you get, [set.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) expects an iterable (e.g. a list), not a single element. Although admittedly the documentation isn't very clear...

Comment: help would be. . . dont be harsh on yourself and keep things simple SET for the win

Comment: Thnx Guys, didn't know .update() expects list. 
.add() worked fine !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a single value, use `add()` instead of `update()`:

```
new_set.add(item)
```